if God is a singular being or entity , why did He use the phrase us before creating man?
It is very clear from the book of Genesis that God who by default refers to the Father, talked to other being(s) and made this statement.
Genesis 1:26

Let  us make man in our image

The verse above shows that those beings The Father was talking to, had the ability to create or make otherwise He would not have involved them in that process, does this make the concept of God plural since that implies more than one creator

This question is similar to: Who is the "us" in Genesis 11:7?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Jason_, my question is different because it seeks answers on the plurality of God based on that statement, whereas the question you linked inquires on the identity of the us

A singular... what? A numerical single; single in purpose? Much clearer definition needs to be given for those who would answer, to know what you have in mind. Even from your comment above, it is obvious that you have something quite different in mind, yet you have not defined what "the plurality of God" means to yourself.

@Anne, I have edited the title to add make the question clearer, that if God is a single being, why use the phrase us to refer to Himself? Why not let me create man, this meant those addressed had the power alongside God to create

Maybe he was just using the majestic plural, also called the royal plural. Please read about the majestic plural in the Bible

@Jason_ says "This question is similar to: Who is the "us" in Genesis 11:7?.". — Not really.  The answers to that are:
"we talk to ourselves",
"evidence of Trinity",
"3 Persons",
and "the two as they are one".
Only the first answer could apply to this question (which requests "if God is a singular being or entity"), and it isn't very strong (e.g. it doesn't say why God talks to himself in early Genesis, but never again).
I'd say it should be reopened.

@RayButterworth, thanks for the opinion to have it reopened. I am challenging the community on the plurality of God based on the phrase us that appears several times in the book of Genesis.

Who is the “Us”?
Genesis 1:26 introduces the plural pronouns “us” and “our,” which appear again in Genesis 3:22 and Genesis 11:7. In other words this is not a singular event. This means we should take multiple scriptures into account. The plural form in Genesis 1:26 suggests a conversation among a plurality with the ability to create.
Genesis 1:26 - “Then God said, ‘Let Us make man in Our image, according to Our likeness…’”
What we know:

The use of “us” and “our” suggests a plurality involved in the
creation process.
Humanity is created in the image and likeness of this plurality,
indicating something like a shared nature or attributes.

Genesis 3:22 - “Then the LORD God said, ‘Behold, the man has become like one of Us, knowing good and evil…’”
What we know:

The “us” possesses the knowledge of good and evil, a divine attribute
that humanity has now acquired.
The plural form again suggests a conversation within a plurality (divine council or among beings with divine attributes.)

Genesis 11:7 - “Come, let Us go down and there confuse their language, so that they will not understand one another’s speech.”
What we know:

The “us” is involved in direct intervention in human activities. In
this case, specifically the confusion of languages at Babel.
The plural form indicates a collective decision and action taken by
this group.


Let's look at some common interpretations of this evidence: [1]
Jewish tradition (Angels)
One traditional Jewish explanation is that God consulted with angels. However, this view has two main counter arguments:

The Bible does not explicitly state that God sought advice from
angels.
Given God’s supreme wisdom and knowledge, it seems unlikely that He
would need to consult angels about creation.

Plurality of gods
Some cults interpret the “us” as referring to a plurality of gods. This line of argumentation suggests that there are multiple gods involved in creation. However, this interpretation conflicts with numerous biblical passages that affirm the oneness of God. (Such as Deuteronomy 6:4, Mark 12:29, and Isaiah 44:6.)
The Trinity
The most widely accepted Christian interpretation is that the “us” refers to the Trinity: Father, Son, and Holy Spirit. The Trinity holds that God is one being in three persons.

I seem to agree with your answer because scripture also refers to another entity who is part of the us as The Lord God, scripture shows the difference between God who is the Father by default and the Lord God who is the Lord of this age, even Jesus Christ

Regarding Gen 3:22 and which supports your point, I noticed something in the LXX.  Αδαμ γέγονεν ὡς εἷς ἐξ ἡμῶν ("Humankind has become as one out of us").  So, I suggest the point is not an attribute of God; but, that the relational unity within the plurality of God is used as a standard against which is measured the relational fracturing that humankind has now experienced.  That is, "Humankind has become as if one of us was ripped from who we are in our relational unity."  This explains how humans now know good and evil--they have experienced it in their relational fracturing.

To further explain...I've wrestled with how human beings can now know good and evil in a way that God has always known good and evil and yet Adam and Eve did not know good and evil before the fall.  There seems to be something illogical swirling around in those events if we take "knowledge of good and evil" as an attribute of God in a way that coincides with pre-fall human knowledge.

"The most widely accepted Christian interpretation is that the “us” refers to the Trinity: Father, Son, and Holy Spirit" Only among English speakers who have never heard of the "royal we" which is still used by the current King for formal speeches, and was used by Elizabeth II even for less formal occasions until well into the 1980s.  The idea that this would be anything else is a simple grammatical error by people who aren't familiar enough with the English language.

@Graham Thank you for sharing your perspective, Graham. I agree that the concept of the “royal we” is indeed familiar in English and other languages. The Trinitarian interpretation is widely accepted among many Christian theologians and scholars globally, not just among English speakers. Additionally, the “royal we” or “majestic plural” is less commonly accepted among Hebrew scholars due to the linguistic context of Biblical Hebrew, where such usage is not typically found with verbs.

On the other hand, I will not ignore the possibility of a "royal we". GotQuestions says: We carefully note that the majestic plural in the Old Testament was not meant to teach the doctrine of the Trinity. It is simply a linguistic tool that God employed to accentuate His greatness. However, the use of plural constructions to refer to God leaves open the possibility of God’s triune nature. Later, when the doctrine of the Trinity is revealed in the New Testament, the use of the majestic plural fits right in.

Well, of course, I being a non-trinitarian, nor a fan of the "plural of majesty" concept, nor indeed "angelic council" concept, we would appear to be left with God and his only begotten, i.e. Word (Logos), the pre-incarnate Jesus, divine also as a matter of consequence - which you only hint at as a possibility - as per the Apostle John's prologue, both of which I see as having a hand in the creation that follows on. If you had been more specific in this direction, in your possible interpretations, I too could have voted this up, but as it is ....

Let's have a look at this shall we?
By which I mean: I'm going to have a look at this.
Grammar is its own world. Grammatical gender isn't what organs something has. Tense isn't when something happened. And number isn't how many there are of a literal thing - it derives that from its original function of conceptualizing a group. (e.g. Fuchs, L. (2008). "From counting to categorization: The role of the classifier in the conceptualization of noun phrases". In Cognitive Linguistics: A Practical Introduction.)

The heavily-standardizing Imperial English of the mid-20th Century has tended to crush this out into the dialects and colloquialisms. (People conceptualizing is never wanted in an empire.) But purely conceptual plurals have survived. Gis a fag! Muggins'll get one then. But I'll have to consult the powers that be.
English is one of the least likely languages to do this - and straight away that's three everyday examples. The whole of the Indo-European and Semitic language families have done plurals-for-singulars since the invention of writing.
Longinus, writing in the 1st Century AD, considered this a type of polyptoton or wordplay.

On the Sublime, 23(2)
φημὶ δὲ τῶν κατὰ τοὺς ἀριθμοὺς οὐ μόνα ταῦτα κοσμεῖν, ὁπόσα τοῖς
τύποις ἑνικὰ ὄντα τῇ δυνάμει κατὰ τὴν ἀναθεώρησιν πληθυντικὰ
εὑρίσκεται...ἀλλ̓ ἐκεῖνα μᾶλλον παρατηρήσεως ἄξια, ὅτι ἔσθ̓ ὅπου προσπίπτει τὰ πληθυντικὰ μεγαλορρημονέστερα καὶ αὐτῷ δοξοκοποῦντα τῷ ὄχλῳ τοῦ ἀριθμοῦ
Indeed, I say that concerning numbers, not only do these decorate, but
as many as are singular in form are found to be plural in force
according to the reconsideration... But those instances merit greater observation, in that wherever the plurals occur, they are more magnificent and seem to lift the multitude of numbers.

Longinus' old testament would have been the LXX, which keeps the plural idiom:-

Genesis 1:26
καὶ εἶπεν ὁ θεός Ποιήσωμεν ἄνθρωπον κατ᾽ εἰκόνα ἡμετέραν καὶ καθ᾽
ὁμοίωσιν· καὶ ἀρχέτωσαν τῶν ἰχθύων τῆς θαλάσσης καὶ τῶν πετεινῶν τοῦ
οὐρανοῦ καὶ τῶν κτηνῶν καὶ πάσης τῆς γῆς καὶ πάντων τῶν ἑρπετῶν τῶν
ἑρπόντων ἐπὶ τῆς γῆς.

'κατ᾽ εἰκόνα ἡμετέραν' would be a headache for the reader/listener if ἡμετέραν isn't a poetic plural, since that requires the 'image' to be a shared semblance of the characteristics the group has in common. When the only person in the group for certain is God, that involves (i) a theological stretch since the other members of the group have features in common with God (ii) a narrative stretch since no other members of the group are described and (iii) a conceptual stretch since the semblance to a diverse group's shared characteristics is asking the reader/listener to supply more information than the more straightforward option of the plural-for-singular.

The phrase us appears more than once in the book of Genesis and there is another entity called the Lord God is a member of the us

@SoFewAgainstSoMany Genesis had to follow the same conventions as all other stories always have done. What's missing from this highly-forced reading is character-establishment, a phrase like "God called his highest angels to discuss the matter" or "God and the Lord and their good friend Yaldabaoth made a counsel" Without that it lands naturally as a plural-for-singular. Compare Iliad 1 mentioning Hera is Zeus' wife. What this other reading needs is examples of characters being introduced to the narrative solely by a grammatical plural - and it's for you as the OP to bring those to the table.

Actually, Hebrew term for God in Tanakh/Old Testament - Elohim is morphologiclaly a plural. While in some places it refers to the unique God, on many occasions it is an actual plural. This opens a range of possibilities, to mention a few:

that speaking of Himself in plural is a kind of honorific self-reference (Like By the Grace of God, We, NN, Emperor and Autocrat of All the Russias,..., similar to French vous and German Sie.)
That He is referring to himself and angels/cherubs/etc.
That He speaks of Himself and other Gods (of which he is the most powerful, and whose existence is not excluded in the early chapters of Tanakh.)


last time I checked, angels do  not have the power to create, only God can create anything at least according to saint John, everything that was made , was made through the word who was God, that meant only God can create and not angels or cherubs lest they boast

@SoFewAgainstSoMany To my knowledge, Saint John is not a part of Torah or even Tanakh, but a later text, not accepted by all the Abrahamic religions. Also, the angels are not acting alone here - just like on other occasions they are empowered by God... and are likely themselves made in His image.

The angels cannot even bring forth a son, they do not have abilities naturally given to man by God, I do not think they can make something out of nothing because that requires direct intervention by God

@SoFewAgainstSoMany As I pointed out above - neither here (nor elsewhere) agents are acting independently. When a mover tells her children "Let us make a lasagna for dinner" - it is clear that it is created via the mother's creative ability, even if children may be actively involved in the process. But if you don't like this option, there are at least more proposed in my answer, and even more in other answers.

There is no crystal clear answer to this but because we're later told that "He" (not they) created suggests that God discussed with the heavenly court what He was going to do and then did it.  We should not assume that angels have the power to create anything, or that angels might have argued with God or prevented God from doing anything.  You might say to a friend "Let's drive over to the beach today", while it is you who is doing the actual driving.  It's simply a figure of speech used to include someone else in your plans.

There are scriptures which imply that God asks angels what should be done about a situation and that an angel volunteers a solution and God agrees.  It's possible God consulted with angels, and also with His only begotten son, about the details of what he proposed to create.  But it also appears that God and God alone has the power to create and did the actual creating.  Many believe that Jesus helped God create or even did the actual creating but that is conjecture without a solid basis.

Rashi, a medieval scholar who authored the primary Jewish biblical commentary,  asks your question on this verse.
He answers that we learn of God's humility from this verse.  God knew that heretics would later use this verse to argue in favor of polytheism, or to deny God, yet He chose to consult his ministering angels, to teach us the trait of humility.
As a refutation of these heretics it is written immediately after this verse “And God created the man”, and it is not written “and they created".
see https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.1.26?with=Rashi for the full text.

The beings addressed here had the power to create or make and that is why they are being involved, and if those beings had that power then they qualify to be God because saint John says everything was made through the Word who was God

God which can be read as a singular entity speaks as a plural entity

@SoFewAgainstSoMany you are claiming that simply being addressed implies the others had the power to create?
